# Unique count and filter formula not displaying counts correctly?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet where I want to look at columns A:C and see a unique count of Products they manage (col A) and have a condition to only count when col C = "Outreach". It seems to be working, but you can see in col F that Ike is being counted although he doesn't have any products with an Outreach status:

[image]

formula is: `=counta(UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,(B:B=E3),C:C="Outreach")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because `FILTER` returns `#N/A` and `COUNTA` treats it as a value. To avoid it you need to wrap `FILTER` in `IFNA` that will return empty value:

```cpp
=COUNTA(UNIQUE(IFNA(FILTER(A:A, B:B=E3, C:C="Outreach"))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [`COUNTUNIQUEIFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9584429?hl=en) function which is a function designed to do exactly what you're trying to do, i.e. counting unique values depending on one or more criteria.

```cpp
=COUNTUNIQUEIFS(A:A,B:B,E2,C:C,"Outreach")
```

[image]